# FFMPEG converting HEVC to VP9 large file size

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9, vaapi

I'm trying to convert HEVC videos to VP9 so they can be played in a web browser while keeping file size roughly the same.

I am struggling to create a video with similar quality/file size.

Here's the stream info for one of the HEVC videos the video is is 22:49 and 168.7mb:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 900 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
```

The bitrate is 900K so I had thought that the following command would use the same bitrate and give a roughly similar image quality:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i "$infile" -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v vp9_vaapi -b:v 900K -bf 2 -bsf:v vp9_raw_reorder,vp9_superframe -c:a libvorbis "$outfile"
```

Using this, the quality is noticeably much, much worse and busy scenes look incredibly blocky though the file size is roughly equivalent to the HEVC source.

If I omit the bitrate and let VP9 work it out

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i "$infile" -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -c:v vp9_vaapi -b:v 0 -bf 2 -bsf:v vp9_raw_reorder,vp9_superframe -c:a libvorbis "$outfile"
```

The quality is visually indistinguishable but the file size of the VP9 converted video reaches 401mb, up from 168mb of the HEVC file and during encoding the bitrate is over 3m for most of the video.

I tried going up to 1.2M (33% higher than the source video) and VP9 still gave a very blocky looking video.

Is VP9 really that much worse than HEVC or is there an option I am missing? or is it because I am converting from HEVC?

Comment: Have you tried with software encoder - libvpx-vp9?

Comment: The software encoder works at about 2fps which isn't really viable as I have about 12 hours of video to encode in total.  In comparison, vp9_vaapi encodes at over 100fps.

Comment: Slow but efficient, or fast and not efficient. Choose one.